# ng-repeat execution forces input to lose focus

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an input that is created using ng-repeat

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="(index, answer) in currentQuestion['possible_answers']" class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Answer {{ index + 1 }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i>
                <input data-ng-model="currentQuestion['possible_answers'][index]" type="text" class="form-control" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want this to prepopulate the inputs with the values that are in `currentQuestion['possible_answers']` and I also want any changes to bind to this variable as well.

However, everytime I start typing into one of these text fields, I type one letter and then it looses focus of the input box. I have a feeling that this is because I start typing and the data bidning updates `currentQuestion`. Because `currentQuestion` is updated, the `ng-repeat` is executed again.

Is there a way to make the `ng-repeat` action a one off action isntead of constantly revalutating?

Comment: Can you try to bind to `answer` instead of using the index and looking it up in thy array again?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes (*[looking at the symptoms, you did not show us the data](http://plnkr.co/edit/D1bK72?p=preview)*) your issue could be because your model is the text in the array that you (may have), so whenever you update the model, it will trigger digest cycle since ng-repeat is tracked by the text. You can easily fix this by providing. `track by $index`, so that the ng-repeat is watched over and repeat watch gets updated only when the array changes in its length.

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="answer in currentQuestion['possible_answers'] track by $index" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Answer {{ $index + 1 }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i>
            <input data-ng-model="currentQuestion['possible_answers'][$index]" type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RiAjqG?p=preview)**

You can also use `$index` to get the array's index. you do not need to iterate with `(key, value)`.

However i would just make my answer array an array of objects and get rid of all these issues, and it would just be (_note the usage of `$index` and `ng-model`):-

```
<div data-ng-repeat="answer in currentQuestion['possible_answers'] track by $index" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Answer {{ $index + 1 }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i>
            <input data-ng-model="answer.text" type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/P3Oles?p=preview)**

Comment: `track by $index` is what I wanted. Only do ng-repeat when the number of items changes.

Comment: @moesef Yup. When you deal woth objects you could set track by with a unique property on the object as well. Basically what happens is when you use track by ng-repeat will not delete and recreate DOM unless it needs to, if the underlying object changes then it will just update. If you deal with objects and you don't specify track by it will add a unique key `$$hashKey` to them, so if you refresh the list it will recreate them again, with track by if you refresh it will only update the existing elements and remove only the ones that needs to be.

Comment: That's pretty great functionality. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` creates a new child scope for each item in the list. In this scope it knows `index` and `answer`. You bind the value of the input to something outside the scope, namely the same item in the array. Changing it triggers the list to be redrawn, which causes the input to loose focus.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(index, answer) in currentQuestion['possible_answers']" class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Answer {{ index + 1 }}</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="input-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i>
      <input data-ng-model="answer" type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried that but then currentQuestion would not bind correctly